# Плавное разворачивание блока сверху вниз

Tags: javascript, html, css

Люди нужна помощь скорее всего подобные вопросы здесь задавались, но все же нужно сделать плавное разворачивание сверху вниз блока при загрузке страницы.

Вот такой способ делает что-то похожее, но только если навестись на этот блок, а нужно что бы это делалось автоматом при загрузке страницы.

```css
.info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #00004d;
    border-top: 5px ridge Crimson;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.info:hover{
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
    <div class="info">
        
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обновил ответ. Добавил вариант на чистом CSS :)

**Решение на JS:**

1. найдите нужный элемент
2. При срабатывании события лоад, задайте стиль найденному элементу.

```js
let info = document.querySelector('.info');
window.onload =  slow();

 function slow(){
setTimeout(function(){ 
info.style.transform = 'translateY(0px)'
}, 1000);

}
```

```css
.info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #00004d;
    border-top: 5px ridge Crimson;
    transform: translateY(-80px);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
 <div class="info">
        
    </div>
```

**Решение на CSS**

```css
.info{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #00004d;
    border-top: 5px ridge Crimson;
    animation: example 1s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {transform: translateY(-80px)}
  100% {transform: translateY(0)}
  
}
```

```html
 <div class="info">
        
    </div>
```

Comment: А это функция записывается как js я правильно понял?

Comment: Да первый вариант это на JS. Но эту задачу, можно ешить на и на чистом CSS. Добавил в ответе )

Comment: Я бы добавил window load или хотя бы DOMContentLoaded (чтоб значть что элемент уже есть на странице) или в связке если это что то типа прелоудера